# Windows shortcut target parameter starting with an @

Tags: windows, shortcut

I have a Windows application that I need to invoke with a desktop shortcut and some command-line parameters.

I've done this thousands of times, but this one is a bit different. Instead of using a normal command-line parameter like `-e 12345` or `-example 12345`, this one uses `@12345` (starting with the `@` symbol).

Windows shortcuts do not like this parameter coming immediately after the executable name, and it just strips everything out. I don't know why.

For example:

`c:\example\example.exe @12345 -e9876` as the "target", when saving, strips out all the parameters and leaves just `c:\example\example.exe` as the target.

*But* `c:\example\example.exe -e9876 @12345` works just fine. It saves, and validates, and everything is good.

*However* I need the `@` parameter to be the first one on the command. Apart from doing something like wrapping the command in a batch file and calling the batch, how can I have an `@` symbol be the first command line parameter on a Windows shortcut?

Comment: The other option is to quote the params (individually), assuming said program supports that. Interesting behaviour I just found on testing, though: the params are gone from the Target field *but* they're still passed to the target program! In fact, the now-invisible params are preserved until you edit the field again, and the `.lnk` files are actually different. (Tested with the target as a batch file that simply echoes the params passed in.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Who knew? ... Windows apparently treats the `@` character as a delimiter.  Windows commands will only interpret the first element in the command... so it effectively truncates the rest.  Apparently, you can override the behavior by supplying a `^` before it to *escape* the symbol.

i.e.

`c:\example\example.exe ^@12345 -e9876`

Comment: Hey! It works! Out of curiosity, how on earth did you find the answer to that?

Comment: Deeeep dark postings of yester-years.  Some person made reference to documents that don't exist anymore (or at least not easy to find) and mentioned some of those tidbits.  He also mentioned things like the `$` and `%` characters that can cause other issues.  You can escape those using the same `^` character.  You can also escape the escape by doing `^^` as you might expect.

Comment: @MarkHenderson The Caret symbol "^" is the standard "escape the next character" symbol used by then entire WIN32 (and later 64-bit) API since (if I recall correctly) at least NT 3.5 (yes: I'm getting old). It works in just about any place in Windows where you can supply a command-line: CMD-scripts/prompt, WIndows+R run box, short-cuts, in the command-lines associated with services and scheduled tasks, just to name a few.